# Is it possible arrayformula combined with many if, and, isblank?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Is it possible arrayformula combined with many if, and, isblank ??

The code below works fine

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F8)=TRUE,ISBLANK(H8)=FALSE), "Not shipped", IF((AND(ISBLANK(F8)=FALSE,ISBLANK(H8)=FALSE)),"Shipped",""))`

I have to make ERP in google spreadsheet

I'm tying to combine arrayformula with upper code.

`=arrayformula(IF(AND(ISBLANK(F8:F)=TRUE,ISBLANK(H8:H)=FALSE), "Not shipped", IF((AND(ISBLANK(F8:F)=FALSE,ISBLANK(H8:H)=FALSE)),"Shipped","")))`

Doesn't work..

I want to put combined arrayformula in G8 cell
It's really bother me

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JMzixU7tdCbHqz-w4m_HYWym1VQPNN73lNs3WyiVPpc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The functions `AND` as well as `OR` do NOT work in arrayformulas.**

One should use the multiplication sign `*` and the addition sign `+` respectively.

So your formula will be

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((ISBLANK(F8:F)=TRUE)*(ISBLANK(H8:H)=FALSE), "Not shipped", 
              IF((ISBLANK(F8:F)=FALSE)*(ISBLANK(H8:H)=FALSE),"Shipped","")))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: it good for me! thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. And thank you for taking the time to accept.